# sql - creating aggregate statistics from tabular data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table

```
Manager-category   StartDate    Enddate
A                  1/1/2002     2/2/2007
B                  1/5/2005     4/5/2005
etc....
```

I need to create summary stats like below (summary)

```
Year   CountofCategoryA who started  CountofCategoryB who started
2003
etc
```

I can generate the above table by making updates for each cell,in Access I use

```
UPDATE summary,
       (A query that gives a count in a year) as counttab
   SET summary.column = counttab.count 
 WHERE summary.Year = currentyear
```

I have to run this query for each cell is there a faster/more efficient way?.

Comment: Cells? Access doesn't have "cells" -- that's a spreadsheet thing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS Expr2
SELECT Year([StartDate]) AS Expr1
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Year([StartDate])
PIVOT SomeTable.[Manager-category];
```